# What is the standard way of declaring sets of constants in Java?

Tags: java

I am writing a Java file to parse files. There are different versions of the files with minor changes - mainly the position of attributes in the files.

So far, I have done it with an abstract class, and sub-classes:

```
public abstract class ChFile {
    int dataStart;
    int startTimePosition;
    int endTimePosition;
    int yOffsetPosition;
    int yScalingPosition;
    int detectorPosition;
    int analystPosition;
    int methodPosition;
    int sampleNamePosition;
    int injectionTimePosition;

    protected ChFile(
            int dataStart,
            int startTimePosition,
            int endTimePosition,
            int yOffsetPosition,
            int yScalingPosition,
            int detectorPosition,
            int analystPosition,
            int methodPosition,
            int sampleNamePosition,
            int injectionTimePosition) {
        this.dataStart = dataStart;
        this.startTimePosition = startTimePosition;
        this.endTimePosition = endTimePosition;
        this.yOffsetPosition = yOffsetPosition;
        this.yScalingPosition = yScalingPosition;
        this.detectorPosition = detectorPosition;
        this.analystPosition = analystPosition;
        this.methodPosition = methodPosition;
        this.sampleNamePosition = sampleNamePosition;
        this.injectionTimePosition = injectionTimePosition;
        }


class ChFile81 extends ChFile {
    private static final int DATA_START = 1024;
    private static final int START_TIME_POSITION = 282;
    private static final int END_TIME_POSITION = 286;
    private static final int Y_OFFSET_POSITION = 636;
    private static final int Y_SCALING_POSITION = 644;
    private static final int DETECTOR_POSITION = 208;
    private static final int ANALYST_POSITION = 148;
    private static final int INJECTION_TIME_POSITION = 178;

    ChFile81(RandomAccessFile input) throws IOException {
        super(
                input,
                DATA_START,
                START_TIME_POSITION,
                END_TIME_POSITION,
                Y_OFFSET_POSITION,
                Y_SCALING_POSITION,
                DETECTOR_POSITION,
                ANALYST_POSITION,
                0,
                0,
                INJECTION_TIME_POSITION)}
```

However, as you can see in the snippet above, having such a big constructor is difficult to maintain, not all information is available in all versions, and so on.

I think the correct move is to refactor to a Builder pattern, but the question on how to store the constant values in the code remains.

Should I do `enum`s? An abstract `Constants` class, with subclasses inheriting for each file version?

What is the canonical way of handling different sets of constant parameters, and load them into an object?

Comment: Is it a fixed set of constants?  If so, static factory methods (like `public static ChFile createFixedInstance`) may be a good approach.

Comment: When you say "constants," I noticed these values are not `public static final`.  So are they really constant or are they determined at runtime?

Comment: @markspace It's a set of real constants. For example, for file version 81, the data starts at byte 1024 in the binary file, the start time is at byte 282 in the binary file, and so on.

Comment: It sounds like those constants are basically configuration settings.  Consider handling those values via a configuration class injected into the processing class.  The constant values could be externalized to config files representing each version to be processed.  A new version would be a new configuration file rather than a code change.

Comment: After hearing more about your use case, I think I agree with Andrew.  A data file that is read at runtime and contains the file constants, rather than trying to make 80+ classes with constants in them, sounds like the way to go.